# Template function to map specific type and leave all other unchanged

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, template-specialization

I'm serializing template pack with fold expression using Boost.Serialization:

```
template <typename ... Args>
std::string toBytes(Args... args)
{
    std::ostringstream buf;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive arch(buf);
    (arch << ... << args);
    return buf.str();
}
```

This works nice, but when I try to serialize a pointer to some basic type (say, `char*`), it chokes on it. I understand that Boost.Serialization doesn't serialize such types out of the box by intent. So, I want to provide a "default" way to serialize them.

To achieve that I want map each `args` element through some function `f`, so that `f(char*)` would return `CharPtrWrapper` and for other types that `f` should work as identity function.

My approach was:

```
template<typename T>
T f(T x) { return x; }

template<>
CharPtrWrapper f(char * x) { return CharPtrWrapper(x); }
```

but this code gives

> error C2912: explicit specialization 'CharPtrWrapper f(char *)' is not a specialization of a function template

What's wrong with that and how do I solve this problem?

Comment: A specialisation must come after the main template. Anyway consider using overloading instead.

Comment: `CharPtrWrapper f(char * x)` doesn't quite match `T f (T x)` does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong with that and how do I solve this problem?

The problem is that your specialization isn't a specialization.

The generic `f<>()` is defined as:

```
template<typename T> 
T f(T x) { return x; }
```

i.e., a template function that receives type `T` and returns the same type. So, a specialization of `f<>()` must return the same type that it receives.

However,

```
template<>
CharPtrWrapper f(char * x);
```

is not a valid specialization for `f<>()` because it receives `char *` and returns `CharPtrWrapper`.

A few valid specializations for `f<>()` are:

```
template <>
char const * f<char const *>(char const * x) { return x; }

// or

template <>
char const * f(char const * x) { return x; }
```

A solution, as suggested by n.m., would be to avoid specialization and use overloading instead. That means, from a practical point of view, to delete the "`template<>`" part and simply write:

```
CharPtrWrapper f(char * x) { return CharPtrWrapper(x); }
```

or better yet, receive a `char const *` instead of a `char *`.